# Avoid duplicate matches in multiple tournament brackets (Optimal Solution?)

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently developing a software to handle tournament brackets in which a player can register to 1...N brackets and he is going to be placed to compete with multiple people in those brackets.

[image: Tournament Brackets]

The problem begins when lets say there are 10 brackets and 1 player registers to all those 10 brackets and he is placed against the same other player in 8 of those 10 brackets since currently the assignment of the bracket position is done randomly. This is where I need help, currently I'm just brute forcing re-assignments until duplicate matches are low. Does anyone have an idea of how to optimize this? The idea is that each player shouldn't have to play against the same other player more than once (when possible).

I don't need code just the idea on how to solve this in a better way.

Comment: What's a "bracket"?

Comment: Bracket is the name for what is displayed in the picture, it's a 8-player mini-tournament where you are placed against another one if you win you advance to the next round until there is only 1 winner.

Comment: So the diagram shows a single bracket?  Each bracket is (or could be) its own separate tournament?

Comment: Exactly and that's where the problem begins as lets say there are 10 brackets in which along multiple other players "Player A" and "Player B" register to compete on all 10 brackets if I were to just assign randomly "Player A" and "Player B" positions in all 10 brackets chances are that they are going to be matched against each other multiple times since it's all random, but if I were to manually assign positions I would match "Player A" and "Player B" so they only compete once against each other in the initial phase of the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as part of the comments but l need more reputation apparently, but if I understand the question correctly, you want to optimise the matching such that each person has at one unique opponent before there is repetition? Maybe you should do an implementation of the modified [stable marriage matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem#Applications) or [perfect matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))? You would find a ranking system for each player and then match them according to how feasible the matchings are.